# How to draw an isometric 3D cube with 3 perfectly identical faces with fillRect?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I would like to create an isometric 3D cube **with fillRect** whose 3 faces have the same dimensions as the image below:

[image]

**Edit:** I want to **do it with fillRect**. The reason for this is that I will draw images on the 3 faces of the cube afterwards. This will be very easy to do since I will use exactly the same transformations as for drawing the faces.

**Edit 2:** I didn't specify that I want to **avoid using an external library** so that the code is as optimized as possible. I know that it is possible to calculate the 3 matrices beforehand to draw the 3 faces and make a perfect isometric cube.

**Edit 3:** As my example code showed, I want to be able to set the size of the side of the isometric cube on the fly (const faceSize = 150).

I have a beginning of code but I have several problems:

- The faces are not all the same dimensions
- I don't know how to draw the top face

```js
const faceSize = 150;
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const centerX = canvas.width / 2;
const centerY = canvas.height / 2;

// Top Face (not big enough)
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(centerX, centerY);
ctx.scale(1, .5);
ctx.rotate(-45 * Math.PI / 180);
ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
ctx.fillRect(0, -faceSize, faceSize, faceSize);
ctx.restore();
  
// Left Face (not high enough)
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(centerX, centerY);
ctx.transform(1, .5, 0, 1, 0, 0);
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fillRect(-faceSize, 0, faceSize, faceSize);
ctx.restore();

// Right Face (not high enough)
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(centerX, centerY);
ctx.transform(1, -.5, 0, 1, 0, 0);
ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, faceSize, faceSize);
ctx.restore();
```

```html
<canvas width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: So essentially, you'd like to fill a hexagon with 3 different colours. I found drawing a repeating pattern of hexagons difficult to draw until I considered the difference between screen-space and model-space (to use an openGL analogy). Once I realized that we can also define its coordinates in a [0..1] space and that they're 86% as wide as they are high, it became obvious. All of the coordinates are either 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75 or 1.0. With the origin at top left, starting at the top vertex, moving anti-clockwise, the verts are <0.5,0>, <0,0.25>, <0,0.75>, <0.5,1>, <1,0.75>, <1,0.25>

Comment: [continued] This coordinate system would place the central vertex at <0.5,0.5>. So, to draw a hexagon 171 pixels high, you can scale all x & y pairs by 171. You can then scale all y values by 0.86 This will then give you coords of the vertices. From there, it's a simple matter of filling 3 4-sided polygons. 3 of the verts come from the outline, while the 4th comes from the central point.

Comment: I really want to make the cube with canvas 2D and fillRect. The reason for this is that I will draw images on the 3 faces of the cube afterwards. This will be very easy to do since I will use exactly the same transformations as for drawing the faces.

Comment: Ohw... I see. Might be worth editing that aim into the question. Well, lets see. I guess you'd need to multiply together the following list of transformations: (1) translateX -1/2 of width, rotate -45deg, scaleX 200%, translateX +1/2 of width. I'm too lazy to set up a matrix for each operation then multiply them together to come up with the a,b,c,d,e,f values though, sorry! An exercise left to the reader. (If the reader thinks my proposed list of operations sounds sane and reasonable)

Comment: Sorry but I can't figure out the correct matrices for transform. Can you post an example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a large part of *@enhzflep's* code which I adapted so that the width of the cube is dynamically changeable.

All the code seems mathematically correct, I just have a doubt about the value **1.22** given as a parameter to **scaleSelf**. Why was this precise value chosen?

[image]

Here is the code:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', onLoad, false);

const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

function onLoad() {
    //canvas.width = cubeWidth;
    //canvas.height = faceSize * 2;
    canvas.width = 400;
    canvas.height = 400;
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    drawCube(canvas);
}

function drawCube() {

    const scale = Math.abs(Math.sin(Date.now() / 1000) * canvas.width / 200); // scale effect
    const faceSize = 100 * scale;
    const radians = 30 * Math.PI / 180;
    const cubeWidth = faceSize * Math.cos(radians) * 2;
    const centerPosition = {
        x: canvas.width / 2,
        y: canvas.height / 2
    };

    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

    const defaultMat = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0];

    // Left (red) side
    const leftMat = new DOMMatrix(defaultMat);
    leftMat.translateSelf(centerPosition.x - cubeWidth / 2, centerPosition.y - faceSize / 2);
    leftMat.skewYSelf(30);
    ctx.setTransform(leftMat);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#F00';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, cubeWidth / 2, faceSize);

    // Right (blue) side
    const rightMat = new DOMMatrix(defaultMat);
    rightMat.translateSelf(centerPosition.x, centerPosition.y);
    rightMat.skewYSelf(-30);
    ctx.setTransform(rightMat);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#00F';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, cubeWidth / 2, faceSize);

    // Top (yellow) side
    const topMat = new DOMMatrix(defaultMat);
    const toOriginMat = new DOMMatrix(defaultMat);
    const fromOriginMat = new DOMMatrix(defaultMat);
    const rotMat = new DOMMatrix(defaultMat);
    const scaleMat = new DOMMatrix(defaultMat);

    toOriginMat.translateSelf(-faceSize / 2, -faceSize / 2);
    fromOriginMat.translateSelf(centerPosition.x, centerPosition.y - faceSize / 2);
    rotMat.rotateSelf(0, 0, -45);
    scaleMat.scaleSelf(1.22, (faceSize / cubeWidth) * 1.22);

    topMat.preMultiplySelf(toOriginMat);
    topMat.preMultiplySelf(rotMat);
    topMat.preMultiplySelf(scaleMat);
    topMat.preMultiplySelf(fromOriginMat);

    ctx.setTransform(topMat);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#FF0';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, faceSize, faceSize);
    ctx.restore();

    requestAnimationFrame(drawCube);
}
```

Comment: I chose 1.22 because that seemed to make the code work. As I said - it was hot here that day - probably about 35 deg C inside. I imagine it'll be the ratio of one side to another somehow. That's how the `((height/2)/width)` term started out - I had it hard-coded as about 0.6 I think, until I thought about the ratio of width to height and realized the sides were being drawn with transformed rectangles, while the top was being drawn with a transformed square. Sorry I can't help further.

Answer (score 0):

If we overlay a circle on your isometric cube, we can see that the outer vertices are spaced equally apart. In fact it's always 60°, which is no wonder as it's a hexagon.

[image]

So all we have to do is obtaining the coordinates for the outer vertices. This is quite easy as we can make a further assumption: if you look at the shape again, you'll notice that the length of each of the cube's sides seems to be the radius of the circle.

With the help of a little trigonometry and a for-loop which increments by 60 degrees, we can put calculate and put all those vertices into an array and finally connect those vertices to draw the cube.
Here's an example:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function drawCube(x, y, sideLength) {
  let vertices = [new Point(x, y)];
  for (let a = 0; a < 6; a++) {
    vertices.push(new Point(x + Math.cos(((a * 60) - 30) * Math.PI / 180) * sideLength, y + Math.sin(((a * 60) - 30) * Math.PI / 180) * sideLength));
  }
  ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(vertices[0].x, vertices[0].y);
  ctx.lineTo(vertices[5].x, vertices[5].y);
  ctx.lineTo(vertices[6].x, vertices[6].y);
  ctx.lineTo(vertices[1].x, vertices[1].y);
  ctx.lineTo(vertices[0].x, vertices[0].y);
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.fillStyle = "#a0a0a0";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(vertices[0].x, vertices[0].y);
  ctx.lineTo(vertices[1].x, vertices[1].y);
  ctx.lineTo(vertices[2].x, vertices[2].y);
  ctx.lineTo(vertices[3].x, vertices[3].y);
  ctx.lineTo(vertices[0].x, vertices[0].y);
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.fillStyle = "#efefef";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(vertices[0].x, vertices[0].y);
  ctx.lineTo(vertices[3].x, vertices[3].y);
  ctx.lineTo(vertices[4].x, vertices[4].y);
  ctx.lineTo(vertices[5].x, vertices[5].y);
  ctx.lineTo(vertices[0].x, vertices[0].y);
  ctx.fill();
}

class Point {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}

drawCube(200, 150, 85);
```

```css
canvas {
  background: #401fc1;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```

## EDIT

What you want to achieve is ain't that easily simply because the `CanvasRenderingContext2D` API actually does *not* offer a skewing/shearing transform.
Nevertheless with the help of a third-party library we're able to transform the three sides in an orthographic way. It's called [perspective.js](https://github.com/wanadev/perspective.js/)

Still we need to calculate the outer vertices but instead of using the moveTo/lineTo commands, we forward the coordinates to perspective.js to actually do the perspective distortion of some source images.

Here's another example:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

class Point {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}

function drawCube(x, y, sideLength) {
  let vertices = [new Point(x, y)];
  for (let a = 0; a < 6; a++) {
    vertices.push(new Point(x + Math.cos(((a * 60) - 30) * Math.PI / 180) * sideLength, y + Math.sin(((a * 60) - 30) * Math.PI / 180) * sideLength));
  }

  let p = new Perspective(ctx, images[0]);
  p.draw([
    [vertices[5].x, vertices[5].y],
    [vertices[6].x, vertices[6].y],
    [vertices[1].x, vertices[1].y],
    [vertices[0].x, vertices[0].y]
  ]);
  
  p = new Perspective(ctx, images[1]);
  p.draw([
    [vertices[0].x, vertices[0].y],
    [vertices[1].x, vertices[1].y],
    [vertices[2].x, vertices[2].y],
    [vertices[3].x, vertices[3].y]
  ]);

  p = new Perspective(ctx, images[2]);
  p.draw([
    [vertices[4].x, vertices[4].y],
    [vertices[5].x, vertices[5].y],
    [vertices[0].x, vertices[0].y],
    [vertices[3].x, vertices[3].y]
  ]);
}

function loadImages(index) {
  let image = new Image();
  image.onload = function(e) {
    images.push(e.target);
    if (index + 1 < sources.length) {
      loadImages(index + 1);
    } else {
      drawCube(200, 150, 125, e.target);
    }
  }
  image.src = sources[index];
}
let sources = ["https://picsum.photos/id/1079/200/300", "https://picsum.photos/id/76/200/300", "https://picsum.photos/id/79/200/300"];
let images = [];

loadImages(0);
```

```css
canvas {
  background: #401fc1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/wanadev/perspective.js/master/dist/perspective.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: I had specified that I wanted to do it with fillRect. The reason for this is that I will draw images on the 3 faces of the cube afterwards. This will be very easy to do since I will use exactly the same transformations as for drawing the faces.

Comment: @Dady - I forgot to mention, I use my own vector/matrix library, but I think you should be able to use an SVGMatrix to compute the final transformation from the 4 transforms I suggested. Though I see they're deprecated and you should use a DOMMatrix instead. Notes here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMMatrix

Comment: Actually, I didn't think it would be so complicated and that it would be necessary to use an external library to do this. Thank you for your example with perspective.js but my goal is to have the most optimized code possible because I will create several cubes on the fly (perspective.js creates two other canvas internally and it does not seem necessary to me to make a 3D isometric cube with transform).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick n dirty approach to the problem. It's too hot here for me to really think very clearly about this question. (I struggle with matrix maths too)
There's 2 things I think worth mentioning, each of which has an effect on the scaling operation.

1. width and height of the finished figure (and your posted example image) are different.
2. I think it's the ratio of the distance between (opposite) corners of the untransformed rectangle which fills 1/4 of the canvas, and the finished yellow side which affect the scaling.

Also, note that I'm drawing a square of canvas.height/2 sidelength for the yellow side, whereas I was drawing a rectangle for the red and blue sides.

In the scaling section, width/4 and height/4 are both shorthand for (width/2)/2 and (height/2)/2. width/2 and height/2 give you a rectangle filling 1/2 of the canvas, with a centre (middle of the square) located at (width/2)/2, (height/2)/2  - height/4 means something different in the translation section (even though it's the same number)

With that said, here's the sort of thing I was talking about earlier.

```js
"use strict";
window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);

function onLoaded(evt)
{
    let width = 147;
    let height = 171;
    let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    drawIsoDemo(canvas);
}

function drawIsoDemo(destCanvas)
{
    let ctx = destCanvas.getContext('2d');
    let width = destCanvas.width;
    let height = destCanvas.height;
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,width,height);
    
    var idMatVars = [1,0, 0,1, 0,0];
        
    // left (red) side
    let leftMat = new DOMMatrix( idMatVars );
    leftMat.translateSelf( 0, 0.25*height );
    leftMat.skewYSelf(30);
    
    ctx.save();
    ctx.transform( leftMat.a, leftMat.b, leftMat.c, leftMat.d, leftMat.e, leftMat.f);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#F00';
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,width/2,height/2);
    ctx.restore();
    
    // right (blue) side
    let rightMat = new DOMMatrix( idMatVars );
    rightMat.translateSelf( 0.5*width, 0.5*height );
    rightMat.skewYSelf(-30);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.transform( rightMat.a, rightMat.b, rightMat.c, rightMat.d, rightMat.e, rightMat.f);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#00F';
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,width/2,height/2);
    ctx.restore();
    
    // top (yellow) side
    let topMat = new DOMMatrix( idMatVars );
    let toOriginMat = new DOMMatrix( idMatVars );
    let fromOriginMat = new DOMMatrix(idMatVars);
    let rotMat = new DOMMatrix(idMatVars);
    let scaleMat = new DOMMatrix(idMatVars);

    toOriginMat.translateSelf(-height/4, -height/4);
    fromOriginMat.translateSelf(width/2,height/4);
    rotMat.rotateSelf(0,0,-45);
    scaleMat.scaleSelf(1.22,((height/2)/width)*1.22);
    
    topMat.preMultiplySelf(toOriginMat);
    topMat.preMultiplySelf(rotMat); 
    topMat.preMultiplySelf(scaleMat);   
    topMat.preMultiplySelf(fromOriginMat);  
    
    ctx.save();
    ctx.transform( topMat.a, topMat.b, topMat.c, topMat.d, topMat.e, topMat.f);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#FF0';
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,height/2,height/2);
    ctx.restore();
}
```

Comment: `setTransform` does accept a DOMMatrix as input directly, so you can remove all these `save()`/`restore()`/`transform(a,b, c...)` to just `setTransform(mat)`.

Comment: @enhzflep Thank you for your example but if I'm not mistaken, you perform the transformations of the matrices with the width and height variables that are hard-coded in the code? My goal is to fill in the width of the side of the cube (const faceWidth = 160; // for example) and that the isometric cube is generated according to that.

Comment: @Dady - you're welcome. Again, I suggest you update the question. I hard-coded in the size of the image you provided, since the question says you want to create a cube with faces the same size as it - & I did. With this inconsistency between the question and the code, it seemed like 150 was your merely your attempt at recreating the image. ;)

Comment: @enhzflep I updated my question. You are currently the one who produced the closest answer to my request but I need to be able to configure "faceSize" on the fly. Do you think you can adapt your code to make this possible?

Comment: @enhzflep I have added an answer using mostly your code. Again, thanks for the matrix calculations as I couldn't have done it without you. However, I have one last question: What is the hard-coded value 1.22 that is given as a parameter to scaleSelf in your code?